# Creating a simple menu using while loop in c++

Tags: while-loop

I'm trying to create a simple program in c++ to calculate the mean, sum, max and min value out of 10 numbers. I want to allow the user to click 4 to stop the program. This is the part of my code I need help with:

```
void printOut(int max, int min, int avr)
{
    int run = true;
    short choice;

    while(run == true)
        {
    cout<<endl<<"1 = mean "<<endl;
    cout<<"2 = max/min "<<endl;
    cout<<"3 = sum "<<endl;
    cout<<"4 = quit "<<endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Mean = "<<avr<<endl;

    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Max = "<<max<<endl<<"Min = "<<min<<endl;
    }
     else if (choice == 3)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Sum = "<<sum<<endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        run == false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error";
    }
        }
}
```

Comment: `run = false;` You do comparison, not assignment.

Comment: I recommend trying to use switch-case instead of if blocks for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty simple and clear way to cope with your problem. Just
set infinite while loop and make exit condition, *or* set this condition directly in the while statement. I used the last approach in this code snippet.

Also, I highly recommend you use a switch-case system to control your input. It would make your code more readable.

Finally, your code should look like this:

```
short choice;

while(choice != 4)
{
    ...
    cin >> choice;
    ...
    switch(choice)
    {
        ...
        case 4:
            cout << "Exit";
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using `run ==` instead of `run =`. `1 = declare`, `2 == test`.
Also, instead of doing `if(run==true)` just use `if(run)`, as then if `run` is true it will show up as `true` and vice versa, so long as it is a `bool`.